# Writing the right jquery selector to retrieve text after a break tag, but inside a div

Tags: jquery, selector

I have some code in the format below that's repeated throughout my page:

```
<div class="video-description-secondary" style="display:block;">
  <h2 class="two">
 Some title text
  </h2>
  <br/>
 Some description text
</div>
```

Here's the problem I'm running into: I want to retrieve the description text (after the br tag and before the closing div tag) using a jquery selector.  I'm not sure how to write the proper jquery selector in order to retrieve that text since the text itself is not inside it's own tag.  I need to apply some code against that text so that I can properly implement a read more/less link.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you? Technically it grabs everything not inside child tags as opposed to whatever is after break.

http://jsfiddle.net/aMKuY/2/

```
 var foo = $('.video-description-secondary').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Alternate Solution

This gives you slightly more control over what is returned. Retrieve all text nodes and then grab last one.

http://jsfiddle.net/aMKuY/3/

```
var textNodes = $('.video-description-secondary').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
});

var val = textNodes[textNodes.length - 1].nodeValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

A selector for that can be written, but I think you should re-evaluate your design. It'd be much easier for you to just wrap the text in some markup and select that instead (that's what it's there for).

So this is better:

```
<div class="video-description-secondary" style="display:block;">
  <h2 class="two">
 Some title text
  </h2>
  <br/>
  <span class='special'>Some description text</span>
</div>
```

which you can access like:

```
$('.special').text();
```

Much cleaner.

Comment: jQuery can often be used in cases where the author of the code does not control the html content.  For instance, I can easily imagine the above code being used in a firefox extension which interfaces with a video download site.

Comment: @starwed truth, but the constraint you mentioned wasn't specified. This may still be the simplest solution for someone facing this issue.